# Javascript code for Div slide down effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to create a Div 'slide down' effect for quite a while now and I found this JS Fiddle which gives an example of exactly what I want; http://jsfiddle.net/L5P2Y/368/ . It uses this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $cont;    
    function tgl_conts(){
        $('.content').stop().animate({height: 0},1200);
        $cont.stop().animate({height:210},1200);
    }

    $('.tab').on('click',function(){
        var tabClass=$(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
        $cont = $('.'+tabClass+':not(.tab)');
        var h = ($cont.height() === 0) ? tgl_conts() :  ( $cont.stop().animate({height: 0},1200) );  
    });

});
```

I've copied all the code, including the HTML and CSS into my own document in the hope that I can just manipulate that into what I want. All I have is this exact code that is on the JS Fiddle, but I still cannot get the JavaScript to work despite it working fine in this example. I've pasted it between the head tags between two script tags but it still does not function. Why isn't it working? Is it in the wrong place? I'm very new to JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting on your page? Is jQuery loaded?

Comment: Did you add the `jQuery` library?

Comment: I think all you need is http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Comment: Do we not get to see your code? The working code won't help.

Comment: Most likely you are missing jQuery 1.7

Comment: Ah thanks, I added the jQuery library and now it works. I had no idea I had to add that - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your code snippet after jQuery 1.7 is loaded on the page

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
// you're code
</script>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Its actually the exact solution the author was looking for :)